# Pandas DataFrame : pick the last day of each month data

Tags: pandas

This is my `DataFrame`:

```
>> df

              open        high         low        close      volume
date                    
2017-01-02  778000.0    787000.0    775000.0    777000.0    30777.0
2017-01-03  777000.0    777000.0    767000.0    767000.0    51766.0
2017-01-04  775000.0    810000.0    771000.0    810000.0    120359.0
2017-02-02  776000.0    780000.0    770000.0    772000.0    121050.0
2017-02-03  770000.0    776000.0    767000.0    774000.0    142414.0
2017-02-06  781000.0    781000.0    772000.0    779000.0    127029.0
2017-03-07  800000.0    806000.0    794000.0    799000.0    48316.0
2017-03-08  798000.0    807000.0    791000.0    800000.0    56378.0
```

What I want to do is to pick the data of last day of each month:

```
              open        high        low        close        volume
date                    
2017-01-04  775000.0    810000.0    771000.0    810000.0    120359.0
2017-02-06  781000.0    781000.0    772000.0    779000.0    127029.0
2017-03-08  798000.0    807000.0    791000.0    800000.0    56378.0
```

What I tried:

```
a.resample('M').apply(lambda x: x[-1])  # Doesn't work => `date` is not correct

              open         high       low        close       volume
date                    
2017-01-31  775000.0    810000.0    771000.0    810000.0    120359.0
2017-02-28  781000.0    781000.0    772000.0    779000.0    127029.0
2017-03-31  798000.0    807000.0    791000.0    800000.0    56378.0
```

Need your help

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are few ways

**1)**

```
In [779]: df.iloc[df.reset_index().groupby(df.index.strftime('%Y-%m'))['date'].idxmax()]
Out[779]:
                open      high       low     close    volume
date
2017-01-04  775000.0  810000.0  771000.0  810000.0  120359.0
2017-02-06  781000.0  781000.0  772000.0  779000.0  127029.0
2017-03-08  798000.0  807000.0  791000.0  800000.0   56378.0
```

or **2)**

```
In [813]: df.loc[df.reset_index().groupby(df.index.to_period('M'))['date'].max()]
Out[813]:
                open      high       low     close    volume
date
2017-01-04  775000.0  810000.0  771000.0  810000.0  120359.0
2017-02-06  781000.0  781000.0  772000.0  779000.0  127029.0
2017-03-08  798000.0  807000.0  791000.0  800000.0   56378.0
```

or **3)**

```
In [810]: df.loc[df.groupby(df.index.to_period('M')).apply(lambda x: x.index.max())]
Out[810]:
                open      high       low     close    volume
date
2017-01-04  775000.0  810000.0  771000.0  810000.0  120359.0
2017-02-06  781000.0  781000.0  772000.0  779000.0  127029.0
2017-03-08  798000.0  807000.0  791000.0  800000.0   56378.0
```

or **4)**

```
In [105]: df.reset_index().groupby(df.index.to_period('M')).last().set_index('date')
```

Details

```
In [783]: df.index.strftime('%Y-%m')
Out[783]:
array([u'2017-01', u'2017-01', u'2017-01', u'2017-02', u'2017-02',
       u'2017-02', u'2017-03', u'2017-03'],
      dtype='<U7')

In [784]: df.reset_index().groupby(df.index.strftime('%Y-%m'))['date'].idxmax()
Out[784]:
2017-01    2
2017-02    5
2017-03    7
Name: date, dtype: int64
```

Comment: `df.loc[df.reset_index().groupby(df.index.to_period('M'))['date'].max()]` this one is the fastest! How can you guys show multiple solution ?? for me not even one..T_T.  Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

You can group by month and then pick the record with the max day of that month:

```
(
    df.groupby(df.date.dt.to_period('M'))
    .apply(lambda x: x.loc[x.date.idxmax()])
    .set_index('date')
)
Out[758]: 
                open      high       low     close    volume
date                                                        
2017-01-04  775000.0  810000.0  771000.0  810000.0  120359.0
2017-02-06  781000.0  781000.0  772000.0  779000.0  127029.0
2017-03-08  798000.0  807000.0  791000.0  800000.0   56378.0
```

Another way is to sort the DF by date first and then take the last row from each month.

```
(
    df.sort_values(by='date')
    .groupby(df.date.dt.to_period('M'))
    .last()
    .set_index('date')
)
```

Comment: @Zero, thanks. I assumed the OP only has 2017 data. I've updated answer to cater for multiple years.

Answer (score 1):

Without `groupby` (work for sorted ddf, if not apply `df=df.sort_index()` firstly )

```
df[~pd.Series(df.index.strftime('%Y%m')).duplicated(keep='last').values]
Out[120]: 
                open      high       low     close    volume
date                                                        
2017-01-04  775000.0  810000.0  771000.0  810000.0  120359.0
2017-02-06  781000.0  781000.0  772000.0  779000.0  127029.0
2017-03-08  798000.0  807000.0  791000.0  800000.0   56378.0
```